# Why DirectoryIndex index.php index.html is not working?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server

I currently use ipage as a host and have a domain pointing to an index.html. However, I need the domain to point to an index.php instead. So I created a .htaccess and only wrote; DirectoryIndex index.php index.html   and saved it but it's not working and users are still being directed to index.html. There is one issue and that index.php is inside a folder called "SourceFolder". So I think the server looks for index.php and can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DirectoryIndex` directive is fine but you need to route request to correct folder.

Have this code in root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^SourceFolder/ SourceFolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

So your default 'root' directory of the website has a folder in it called SourceFolder, and the index.php file is in there?

If so, then simply do the following inside htaccess.

```
DirectoryIndex SourceFolder/index.php
```

This will look for index.php inside SourceFolder.